# Can't get z-index to work on these css background elements

Tags: css, z-index

I'm trying to improve my css a little, specifically use of z-index to overlap elements and change stack order. I created this fiddle but when I change the values of the z-index, the layers stay the same. I can't get z-index to do anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/AfPWE/24/

Without using a z-index, a div inside of another div always appeared on top. I tried to put it underneath the container div using z-index but with no luck. So then I thought maybe divs that are inside of each other can't have their stack order changed, so I made another div outside of those but couldn't change it's stack order either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work as the `z-index` of an element is inherited from its parent. To get this to work, you'll have "de-child" the elements:

```
<div id="green"></div>

<div id="black"></div> 

<div id="pink"></div>
```

And also `z-index` needs to have a position also, but you have that.

Comment: but that's why I created the red box that wasn't a parent or child of the others, but I still couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Divs that overlap need to be at the same level as each other. Check this fiddle out:
http://jsfiddle.net/jmqwZ/

I've created an "other" div at the same level as the pink one. You can try to swap their z-indexes.

Comment: No problem, here's a great video from CSS-tricks that explains it as well: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/40-how-z-index-works/